# Coding Help: Blender to Arduino over Serial Port

Tags: arduino, robotics, arduino-uno

Working on a connecting an Arduino Uno to Blender 3.4 over the serial port. In the Blender file, I have an object named "motor1", a simple cube that can be manually rotated in the 3d viewport. I'd like to send that rotation data to the Arduino, and let the Arduino use it to move a stepper motor. Also, currently using a CNC shield as an interface.

In short: Blender cube rotates 90 degrees = the stepper motor turns 90 degrees.

The problem: I believe I am getting no communication over the serial port. I have tested the Arduino/shield/motor setup with other non-serial codes, and I get the appropriate motor movement. I've tested the serial connection between the Arduino and Blender, again with a much simpler code, and had success.

Hoping someone can take a look at these two scripts and let me know if they are seeing anything.

Arduino source code:

```cpp
#include <AccelStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, 2, 5); //step pin is 2, direction pin is 5

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); //enable pin is 8
  digitalWrite(8, LOW); //set enable pin low to enable the stepper motor
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(500); // set the maximum speed of the stepper motor
  stepper.setAcceleration(1000); // set the acceleration of the stepper motor
}

String readString() {
  String inString = "";
  char inChar;
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    inChar = (char) Serial.read();
    inString += inChar;
    delay(1);
  }
  return inString;
}

int* parseString(String msg) {
  static int a[2];
  int commaIndex = msg.indexOf(',');
  a[0] = msg.substring(0, commaIndex).toInt();
  a[1] = msg.substring(commaIndex+1).toInt();
  return a;
}

void writeValues(int b[]) {
  if (b[0] < 20) b[0] = 20;
  if (b[0] > 150) b[0] = 150;
  int steps = map(b[0], 20, 150, 0, 500); // map the angle to the number of steps
  stepper.moveTo(steps); // move the stepper motor to the desired number of steps
  Serial.print(b[0]);
  Serial.print("        ");
  Serial.println(b[1]);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    String incoming = readString();
    int* angles = parseString(incoming);
    writeValues(angles);
  }
  stepper.run(); // run the stepper motor
}
```

And the Blender script:

```python
import bpy
import math
import time
import sys
import serial

ob = bpy.data.objects['motor1']
offset = 30

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)
print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

def sendAngle():
    angle = str(round(math.degrees(ob.rotation_euler.z) + offset))
    print(angle)
    ser.write(angle.encode('UTF-8'))

def frameChange(passedScene):
    sendAngle()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frameChange)
```

Comment: So you wrote them and they don't work. What have you done to verify which parts work and which part don't? Can you send or receive even one character and react to it, and then continue further?

Comment: I have used the information that directly relates to the stepper (step and drive pins, accel, speed) in a separate script, that asked the motor to go to 90 degrees, stop, go back 90 degrees, stop, and on and on. However, this wasn't using a serial connection. This was just to ensure the motor, and the board and the connections were all working.  I am very new to coding and have pieced this together with help and research. I used an entirely separate pair of scripts to communicate between blender and arduino, to test that the serial connection could be made. This was a basic "hello world" code.

Comment: stop trying to build the whole program all at once ... start with sending one single byte to Blender ... if Blender has a terminal console, then send it there